# if statement conditional flow using ! operator

Tags: if-statement, arduino, conditional-statements

I am looking at some Arduino compatible code specifically designed for working with Serial Flash Memory, but I'm coming up against a more general question about if() statements and conditional flow of a program.  It is a new technique I have not seen before.  The original code can be accessed here:https://github.com/LAtimes2/DataLogger/blob/master/DataLogger.ino

This code works fine, and does what it is intended to do, that is not the question here...just FYI.

The code I am having a hard time understanding, in the void loop() is as follows:

```
logging = true;
    if (logging) {
          logString = valueToLogString (temperature, currentTime);

          if (!dataLogger.writeData (logString.c_str(), logString.length())) {
            if (!flashFull) {
              Serial.print ("Flash data is full - stopped writing\n");
              flashFull = true;
            }
          }
          // also print to serial port
          Serial.print(logString);
        }
      }
```

The function dataLogger.writeData, called in the code above, is as follows:

```
bool SerialFlashDataLogger::writeData (const void *buf, uint32_t wrlen) {

  uint32_t lengthWritten = 0;

  lengthWritten = dataFile.write (buf, wrlen);

  // return false if all the data was not written
  return (lengthWritten == wrlen);
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding the if() statement:

> if (!dataLogger.writeData (logString.c_str(), logString.length()))

The code is designed to continuously log data, so why is there an if(!dataLogger.writeData.....) -- which reads if ("NOT"dataLogger.writeData....)

I think it has something to do with how the "writeData" function is defined and the fact that it returns a boolean value, but I just can't seem to get my head around how this helps the writeData function continuously accept inputs in order to write to the memory chip?

There is something I'm missing in the logic here.

I know this is perhaps a confusing post...hopefully it is clear to someone ;0

Comment: I think, you should learn language basics before engaging complex projects.

Comment: 1) Arduino is not C and not exactly C++ 2) "I know this is perhaps a confusing post...hopefully it is clear to someone" - Make up your mind and first know what you want to ask. If you have trouble with an operator, read a book or tutorial. There is enough information to be found. You are required to show at least **some** research effort on your own. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a log file in the flash memory, which is represented by the variable `dataFile`:

```
 lengthWritten = dataFile.write (buf, wrlen);
```

As long as there is space available, the call to `dataLogger.writeData` will return true.

Once the disk is full, the call to `dataFile.write` will end up writing less bytes than requested, hence, `dataLogger.writeData` will return false:

```
// return false if all the data was not written
return (lengthWritten == wrlen);
```

I think there should be a check for `flashFull` somewhere before calling the logging function (somewhere before `if (logging) {` ) in order to prevent from printing too many error to the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

When `expr` is of type `bool`, `if (!expr)` is the same as `if (!expr == true)`, or `if (expr == false)`.

So, it's what it says.

> ```
> // return false if all the data was not written
> ```

The conditional is then seeing whether "all the data was not written".

The code within the `if` is executed only if "all the data was not written".

Answer (score 0):

The writeData function return a boolean, as you can see there `bool SerialFlashDataLogger::writeData`. This boolean tells you if all data have been written or not, so you can use this in a boolean expression in a conditional statement

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help...this makes sense now...the part I was missing in my understanding of how this works, has to do with the concept that the writeData function is called FIRST, which then logs the data internally in that function, and then it is evaluated if it is returning FALSE or TRUE, which then is reversed with the NOT, and passed over if it evaluates to False after the reversal...I wasn't clear on how the inputs could get into the function with the NOT operator there...

An interesting and concise trick to remember for the future.

Thanks!